# Fish is not returning to new line after executing bind

Tags: fish

I'm binding Ctrl+f to `fg` so I can Ctrl+z and Ctrl+f back into vim. However after two times doing the combo twice, it ruins the terminal:

```
user@pc:~$ vim
Job 1, 'vim' has stopped
user@pc:~$ Send job 1, “vim” to foreground
Job 1, 'vim' has stopped
^F▉
```

Cursor is now not on a line (which begins with `user@pc`) and executing any command show it as string (`^F`as example).

Pressing enter fixes this, but there should be a better solution.

**Edit:** using `bind \cf 'fg; commandline -f repaint'` shows the PS1, but it's still in text mode, meaning pressing Ctrl+f, doesn't run `fg` but outputs `^F`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to instad of using:

```
bind \cf 'fg'
```

use:

```
bind \cf 'fg; commandline -f execute'
```

It ocassionaly does an extra enter, but whatever.